# Detect what 'button' is pressed

Tags: autohotkey

I just started using autohotkey and I already got 1 question:

Is there a way to detect which button is 'pressed' without listing any keys that it should look for? As in, detect ANY button pressed.

The reason I want this is because I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to detect the volume up/volume down keys on my earphones. I want to know if autohotkey can, somehow, detect them and if it does, what 'keyword' it assigns to it.

**Note:**

The volume up/down buttons on my earphones aren't 'recognized' by Windows on default. So they don't work as media buttons, which I do try to achieve.

Comment: Follow the steps described under [Special keys](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm#SpecialKeys).

Comment: Where do you plug those earphones, in the stereo jack? I don't think a PC can receive signals from there.

Answer (score 19):

IMHO, it's nigh impossible to find what you want quickly in the AHK documentation.

Here's a step by step.

1. Double click the AHK logo in the taskbar
   [image]
2. Select `View > Key History and Script Info` or press `Ctrl + K`
   [image]
3. Type some junk like "Hello, world!"
4. Select `View > Refresh` or press `F5`.  The key you pressed will be on the right.  You may need to scroll down in the output window.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work in AHK 1.1.33.0, at least not on 64-bit Windows 10 Home 1903 OS build 18362.959, and I can't find the new method (if any). Specifically, double-clicking the AHK logo in the taskbar does not do anything. No sound, no window, no nothing.

Comment: Weird.  I don't have a Windows PC handy.  Looks like they have a 1.1.33.02 release available on their homepage.  Looking at Git, I don't see anything in the release notes about that.  Maybe file a bug if the latest doesn't fix your issue: https://github.com/Lexikos/AutoHotkey_L/tags

Comment: At least as of v1.1.33.06, one has to include the following statement in the script: `#InstallKeybdHook`

Answer (score 6):

[As MCL mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18693881/detect-what-button-is-pressed#comment27538905_18693881), you can try the steps for [Special Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm#SpecialKeys) in AutoHotkey's documentation.

<sub>(**Note**: This may not work for headphone volume buttons, as most PC headphone jacks don't support [3 stripe TRRS signals](https://superuser.com/a/1209585/358766))</sub>

> #### [Special Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm#SpecialKeys)
>
> If your keyboard or mouse has a key not listed above, you might still
>   be able to make it a hotkey by using the following steps:
>
> 1. Ensure that at least one script is running that is using the [keyboard hook](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_InstallKeybdHook.htm). You can tell if a script has the keyboard hook by
>      opening its main window and selecting "View->[Key history](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/KeyHistory.htm)" from
>      the menu bar.
> 2. Double-click that script's tray icon to open its main window.
> 3. Press one of the "mystery keys" on your keyboard.
> 4. Select the menu item "View->[Key history](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/KeyHistory.htm)"
> 5. Scroll down to the bottom of the page. Somewhere near the bottom are the key-down and key-up events for your key. NOTE: Some keys do
>      not generate events and thus will not be visible here. If this is the
>      case, you cannot directly make that particular key a hotkey because
>      your keyboard driver or hardware handles it at a level too low for
>      AutoHotkey to access. For possible solutions, [see further below](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm#SpecialKeys).
> 6. If your key is detectable, make a note of the 3-digit hexadecimal value in the second column of the list (e.g. **159**).
> 7. To define this key as a hotkey, follow this example:
>
> ```
> SC159:: ; Replace 159 with your key's value.
> MsgBox, %A_ThisHotKey% was pressed.
> return
> ```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `<KeyHistory>` to get which keys you are/have pressed. Once that is determined, you can then use `<GetKeyState>` to see if the key has been pressed or not.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a struggle but I managed to figure it out.
You need to have a script running to check out the "Key history & key info" window but that feature behaves differently based of the contents of the script you run.

Since I downloaded AHK for this purpose specifically I was using the first example script in the docs as my dummy script which only shows its own output & nothing about other keys pressed

```
^j::
Send, My First Script
return
```

Doing the same thing but running this other script I managed to record the keys I needed, hope this helps others with the same issue as me

```
SC159:: ; Replace 159 with your key's value.
MsgBox, %A_ThisHotKey% was pressed.
return
```